# Restrict admin access to certain pages based on page slug

Tags: wp-admin, slug

I'm trying to do exactly what is done with this question - [Restrict admin access to certain pages for certain users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/restrict-admin-access-to-certain-pages-for-certain-users)

Except I want to use a page slug to restrict the users by. So instead of

```
$query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array('123','234','345');
```

I want to be able to use

```
$query->query_vars['post__not_in'] = array('home','about-us','contact');
```

Appreciate the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok team, I figured this out and its real simple. Use get_page_by_path to retrieve pages and get their slugs and pass it as an array object which is converted to an array of post ids. Since home pages dont have slugs, I had to use get_option to grab the id of the front page and push that in the array.

```
 function hide_pages_in_admin($query)
{
    // Create array of all the slugs you wanna hide
    $hidden_slugs = array('about-us', 'contact', '404');

    // Loop through slugs & pass each slug as page path value
    foreach ($hidden_slugs as $hidden) {
        $hidden_slugs[] = get_page_by_path($hidden)->ID;
        // In case you need to hide the home page too
        $hidden_IDs[] += get_option('page_on_front');
    }

    // Select the user type to hide pages from
    if (current_user_can('editor')) {
        // Pass the array as value to the query vars filter 
        $query->query_vars['post__not_in'] =  $hidden_slugs;
    }
}
add_filter('parse_query', 'hide_pages_in_admin');
```